# Is it possible to pass a function via state params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

How to pass the function as a state params, using react router with props.history.push method.

```
const myFun = () => {
  console.log("do something");
}
```

Ex:

```
props.history.push({
      pathname: "/myrouterpath",
      state: {
         myFun: myFun 
      },
    });
```

if I do like this I am getting error **Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': function myFun() {} could not be cloned**
Please help me in this.

Comment: `props.history.push({ pathname: '/product', query: { myFun: myFun }});`, you can use query for that. not tested

Comment: You can't. read wc3 web history api https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/browsers.html#history, it returns as a serialized state, which deserialized into an object. which mean you can't put function into it

Comment: Yes your right syarul, I can't pass the function via params, we can pass only string. do we have any alternative way to achieve with exporting myFun function.

Answer (score -2):

> app.js

```
$stateProvider

    <omitted>

    .state('send-to', {
      url: '/send-to',
      templateUrl: 'templates/send-to.html',
      controller: 'SendToCtrl'
    })
```

> controllers.js

```
.controller('SendToCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

    console.log($stateParams);
```

Comment: its not in angularjs, its in reactJs with react router.

Comment: yap but procedure same bro.